# Hook to extract text from Windows Explorer

Tags: winapi, hook, detours, easyhook

I am trying to hook in to draw text API of Windows (DrawTextW,ExtTextOutW) to get the text but I can't get the text location correctly in address bar of Windows Explorer

Seems it has specific way in drawing. 
Anyone knows how it draws?
Please advise.

Comment: As far as I know, everything displayed in Explorer windows is available from public APIs.  You can even determine [what folder is being displayed in an Explorer window](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/20/188696.aspx).  Unless you have some really, really odd requirements, just use the public APIs.

Comment: Use the accessibility interfaces. That's what they're for.

Comment: Accessibility is good but actually, I would like to get text by hooking windows GDI APIs. I can get the text but it has wrong location only. I see the text is drawn by DrawTextW and Bitblt, but it may use clipping specially here. There are some icons beside the text. I have no idea how it uses clipping in this case.

Comment: Why do you need to hook GDI to get the text? What text are you trying to extract that is not publically accessible through other APIs?